# How to query mongodb between dates only by ObjectID?

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp

i dont have in my collection any date attributes,
how can i query something like this:

```
db.myCol.find(  {
               "DateOf(_id)" : 
                              {"$gt": sometimestamp }
                })
```

i tried many thing but nothing works, how can i query it?

i have only this attributes:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "512cd2a0e4b0e3f4bfb06011" ),
  "username" : "test",
  "device_id" : "353918053821035",
  "phone_type" : "GSM",
  "new" : false }
```

Comment: Give a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327296/how-do-i-extract-the-created-date-out-of-a-mongo-objectid

Comment: The above does not work so well in most cases, this answer works better most of the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date