# How to delete data in MongoDB by create date?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a MongoDB with 380k documents in it and I want to delete all documents which are created before specific date.
Can anyone help me with writing query for this task?
Thank you.

Comment: [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327296/how-do-i-extract-the-created-date-out-of-a-mongo-objectid) might help

Answer (score 1):

The `ObjectId` of the document is basically contains timestamp. So you can easily construct `ObjectId` from timestamp and use `$lt` operator just like this (python code):

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
ts = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
doc_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(ts)
result = collection.find({"_id": {"$lt": doc_id}})
```