# Adding date type to the documents already created

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I have my mongoose schema defined as follows.

```
mongoose.Schema({
    "url": String,
    "translations": [
        {
            "targetLang": String,
            "source": String,
            "target": String
        }
    ],
}, { versionKey: false });
```

I updated my schema to include `createdAt` and `updatedAt` with the new schema looking as:

```
mongoose.Schema({
    "url": String,
    "translations": [
        {
            "targetLang": String,
            "source": String,
            "target": String,
            "createdAt": { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            "updatedAt": { type: Date, default: Date.now }
        }
    ],
}, { versionKey: false });
```

So when new documents are created, the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` is auto-populated, as expected. How can I have the old documents with the new key `createdAt` and `updatedAt`. Is there any way?

**Note:** I am okay with the old documents to have the current or any previous date. But I want all of them to have a date.

Comment: You can check the answer to this question to extract the creation date from the ObjectId of the document: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327296/how-do-i-extract-the-created-date-out-of-a-mongo-objectid

Comment: @makmonty I am okay with the old documents to have any old date and not necessarily looking to have the exact creation date because the array would have been updated multiple times.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with one single command, you'll have to do some scripting to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update them manually, from mongoshell for example:

```
{
    const toUpdate = db.getCollection('collection').find({
        $or: [
            { 'translations.createdAt': null },
            { 'translations.updatedAt': null }
        ]
    });

    toUpdate.forEach(doc => {
        const timestamp = doc._id.getTimestamp();
        doc.translations.createdAt = timestamp;
        doc.translations.updatedAt = timestamp;
        
        db.getCollection('collection').updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: doc });
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem @Amanda has is that the documents are nested in an subarray, not in the top level. This code will add createdAt and updatedAt to the top level of every document.

Comment: Could you suggest a way with mongoose?

Comment: This is a one-time fix, why would you include it in your codebase? Anyway, it should work with mongoose as well I think, if you remove the outer curly braces

Comment: Is there a way to auto-update the `updatedAt` field when the update happens inside `translations` ? Currently,  I have to explicitly pass the `date` while updating.